# Upgrading OpenSSH von AWS EC2

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, openssh

I ran an **PCI Compliance** scan over my system and some vulnerabilities are saying that I have to **upgrade openSSH version** of my server.

How can I achieve this using **AWS Ec2 Instance Ubuntu 16.04**?

Solution provided from "Nessus":

> https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/96151

Furthermore some vulnerabilities are caused by the current **TLS** Version used. Currently it's just LetsEncrypt Certificate. Am I right that when I purchase a certificate those vulnerabilities will be gone? Because the **"bought ones" are not TLS v1.0** ?

Comment: I would suggest you to check if that vulnerability is false positive and read about backporting. Also **PCI compliance requires that your server run TLS version 1.2 or greater**
More info https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/PCI+Compliance+and+Software+Versions

Comment: I already disabled TLS1.0 and 1.1 thank you found it out few minutes ago. What do you mean with "false positive"?

Comment: For example, an operating system developer may combine OpenSSL 0.9.7c with a patch from OpenSSL 0.9.7.d to create OpenSSL 0.9.7c-2. If most PCI scanning systems look for OpenSSL version 0.9.7d or higher, they may incorrectly show OpenSSL 0.9.7c-2 as vulnerable. In this case, you would inform the PCI compliance company that you use a backported version of the software package, which its developers patched for the vulnerability. Your PCI compliance company can then record your software version and mark a false positive in the scan results.

Comment: okay I understand. Thank you

Comment: You can check that link. which provides steps to mitigate the issue and let us know if that works.

Comment: The command "rpm -qa | grep openssl" or "rpm -qa | grep openssh" does not deliver any results on my machine? I had to sudo apt install rpm

Comment: Those command are for finding package on redhat. You try dpkg -l | grep (package name)

Comment: Delivers the following output: https://ibb.co/J5P220V